# SQL side grouping of field before plugging into Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

My company uses numbers as a system identifier to branches. The problem is my end users do not like seeing 000201 as a branch name. Therefore I am trying to convert these numbers to a string and then roll up the satellite locations into the main branch. The branch format is as follows:

BBBBSS so, as an example, the Nashville main branch will follow 000201 and all satellites would follow sequentially 000202, 000203, 000204.

I want all of our details to roll up into "Nashville". So any instance that ORGID is like 0002** it would roll up everything into a field named "Nashville".

Sorry if I'm not too clear. I've been banging my head against the wall so my thoughts are jumbled.

Comment: Your requirement very confusing. Can you edit your question and make it simpler (may be list points). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, there are at least Two ways i can think of accomplishing this ;

The 1st way is straight forward, you'd add a case statement for each Branch, if you have many branches i'd go with the 2nd way.

```
Select  case SUBSTRING(cast(Branch.Id as varchar(10)), 1, 4 ) 
        when '0002' then 'Nashville' 
        when '0003' then 'Branch 03' 
        when '0004' then 'Branch 04'
        else SUBSTRING(cast(Branch.Id as varchar(10)), 1, 4 ) end   OrgName, 
        COUNT(*) 
from Branch group by SUBSTRING(cast(Branch.Id as varchar(10)), 1, 4 )
```

This 2nd way you would have a separate table to Hold Branch Name, etc. For demonstration i will call this table OrgTable with a OrgId containing your "0002" Ids, and a OrgName containing the "Nashville".

```
Select OrgTable.OrgName, count(*)
from Branch
inner join OrgTable on ( OrgTable.OrgId = SUBSTRING(cast(Branch.Id as varchar(10)), 1, 4 ))
Group By OrgTable.OrgName
```

I haven't checked that the SQL above is without syntax errors, but hopefully you get the picture.

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple formula in CR to convert your ORGID to the branch name:

```
//Convert ORGID to string and save branch code
local stringvar branch := left(totext({Table.ORGID},0,''),4);

//Display city based on branch code
select branch
case "0002" : "Nashville"
case "0003" : "Other City"
<...>
default : "No matching branch!"
```